# Find flaw in solving for coefficients of $e^x = A_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

\begin{align*}
  e^x &\sim A_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} \\
\end{align*}

The Fourier cosine series on the right will be even extended periodized version of $e^x$.

Now, I could solve for these coefficients directly,

\begin{align*}
  A_n &= \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L e^x \cos \frac{n \pi x} \, dx \\
\end{align*}

But this exercise asks for a different solution.

We can apply term by term differentiation to yield:

\begin{align*}
  e^x &\sim - \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \pi}{L} A_n \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L} \\
\end{align*}

Setting the two definitions of $e^x$ equal yields the following which is equality for $[0,L]$:

\begin{align*}
  A_0 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} &\sim - \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \pi}{L} A_n \sin \frac{n \pi x}{L} \\
\end{align*}

From there, how can I derive $A_n$?

**EDIT**: I found my original flaw, that last equation is only equality for $[0,L]$, not for $[-L,L]$. However, I'm still not sure how to calculate $A_n$ via this technique.

Comment: To get a series of cosines only you need a variant of $e^x$ that is both periodic and even. So something like $e^x$ when $x\in[0,L]$ and $e^{-x}$ when $x\in[-L,0]$. The plot of the resulting function will have cusps at integer multiples of $L$ so won't be differentiable there. Anyway, you end up calculating integrals such as $\int_0^Le^x\cos(n\pi x/L)\,dx$. Those you can do with a  table indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^x$ is a mixed parity function which is neither even  nor odd, so the fouries series will have  both the compnents: $\sin (n x/L)$ and $\cos (nc/L)$.

Comment: Obviously, $e^x$ isn't even or odd, it's also not periodic either, but you can take $e^x$ over a period $[0,L]$ and make an even extended periodic version of that, which is what the Fourier Cosine series should converge to.

Comment: For Fourier expansion the function need not be periodic one can discuss the function only in $[-L,L].$